# Reverse proxy preventing Laravel from sending headers to client

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, http-headers, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

I am deploying a Laravel REST API in Amazon EC2 and using Application Load Balance (ALB) as reverse proxy. So, the architecture is basically   *Client  -> Route 53 (resolve DNS) -> Load Balancer ALB (reverse proxy) -> EC2 instance with Ubuntu and my Laravel Application*.

Since Laravel uses Symfony library to handle proxies, I followed [this Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) and [this Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly) to set up my ALB as a **trusted proxy** in my Laravel app, making my EC2 instance accessible only **through** my ALB - but I can also access my EC2 through SSH - leaving me with the `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` as below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string|null
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB; // Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

So, apparently my app can receive HTTP headers from clients through the reverse proxy headers, specifically `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB`.

However, the client application is **not receiving HTTP Response headers** at all, such as CORS (and I am using Laravel default `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors` library to handle CORS) or `'Accept': 'application/json'`, leading to CORS errors on the client side.

So, in other words, my Laravel app response headers will not getting through my reverse proxy ALB.

Does anyone know what is happening and how/if can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to verify that the HTTP response exiting the EC2 instance contains the correct reply headers.  You could run tcpdump on the EC2 instance to verify that. That will at least confirm if it is the ALB that is causing the problem.